# All the contents under "/" are now under "/@"

Tags: boot

Since a couple of days ago when I turn on my computer I get the GRUB terminal. I've launched Live Ubuntu from a USB and I've mounted the partition, only to see that where I should have all my contents (`/`) I now have:

- `@`: Has everything that should be on `/`, (`bin`, `boot`, `initrd.img`... everything)
- `boot`: I think I installed this myself, because I reinstalled Grub (under @/boot there's another grub, which I assume is the real one...)
- `@home`: my personal data. Under `@/home` there's nothing.
- `@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-wily-...`: no idea.
- `@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-xenial-...`: no idea.

Basically all the data has gone under `/@/` except for `/home` that is now in `/@home`. What should I do? Save my data and reinstall ubuntu?

Thanks!

I've been trying to search this issue on google but is wont search the `@` symbol.

I've run the command suggested in the comments and this is what I got (aprox):

- UUID=[...] / btrfs defaults,subvol=@ 0 1
- UUID=[...] /home btrfs defaults,subvol=@home 0 2

If you need all the data tell me and I'll copy it, but I assume this maps the `/` with the `/@` somehow, so my original assumption is actually not my problem, right? I've also checked the `grub.conf` file under `/@/boot/grub` and it's referencing everything OK (with the `/@/...`)... so perhaps the problem has to do with the grub installed in `/boot/` instead of `/@/boot/`?

Comment: What is the output of `grep -v ^# /etc/fstab` and `df`. add it to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina Should I copy the `df` as well? I don't know if it makes sense since I'm running ubuntu from a live usb now... in fact I ran the `grep` not in `/etc/fstab` but in `/media/.../@/etc/fstab`.

Comment: So only post the `fstab` contents.

Comment: @Ravexina I've tried to do so in the post. As I'm writing from another computer and I had to manually copy it, I didn't copy everything, but I think with that should me enough, tell me otherwise.

Comment: Actually I've just copied `/@/boot/grub/grub.cnf` to `/boot/grub/grub.cnf` and it solved the problem... :) thank you anyway for telling me about `fstab`! It took me into the right path.